# Rectangle extraction after Canny OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition, edge-detection

I feel a bit lost with how I should configure Canny edge detection. Maybe someone could lead me on the right path.

I'm trying to detect the highlighted option in a menu. I have two images, and it works on one, but I couldn't get it working for another one regardless of how I tried to fiddle with the parameters. When looking at the edges picture output, the rectangle edges seem clear, so I don't understand why it isn't picking the rectangle up.

The images that I've been using are these:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/eLC0Jep.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/y2RctK3.png]

My code is here:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('sublime.png')

edges = cv2.Canny(img, 210, 255)
copy = edges.copy()

img2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(copy, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

image = 0

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True) #Removes tiny deviations, tries to go for straight lines.
    if len(approx) == 4: #Lines, should be square.
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if w > 10:
            print("Width and height: ", w, h)
            image = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
cv2.imshow('area', image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Don't look for edges, look for blue pixels.

Comment: @JonathanDeer work with the blue channel of the image